# Alternative to "background-size" CSS property

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider, carousel, css

I've been struggling for days with a problem, all without success. So, here I am asking for your help again.

The problem: on **[THIS](http://www.petrebogdan.com/vital/)** website I have a slideshow powered by the [jQuery Infinite Carousel Plugin](http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-infinite-carousel-plugin/). I have added `background-size: auto 100%;`
to the thumbnail divs (for obvious reasons), but this CSS piece is not understood by IE8 and bellow.

My question: is there an old browser-compatible alternative to `background-size`? Is there a hack?

Thank you!

Comment: There's a good answer to this question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715766/support-background-size-property-on-older-browsers][1] by @Spudley.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715766/support-background-size-property-on-older-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/VMzFB/

CSS:

```
#stretch {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -10;

    /* only ie7 needs this */
    height: 100%;
}
#stretch img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="stretch">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/256x256/f0f/fff" />
</div>
```

If that's not quite right, look at the ideas here:

http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I'm not looking for a full page background solution. I need to *fit background images into small divs*. Click **[HERE](http://www.petrebogdan.com/vital/)** to see the page.