# Full Size Background Image Crossbrowser CSS

Tags: css, background, background-image

I've been trying to use a full image as background, I already used all these methods:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

...and they do work but in some resolutions the image gets cutted. Does anyone have come with a clean crossbrowser solution for a Full Background Image that doesn't use Jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Could you specify your exact requirements? If the image should never get cut, how could it retain its aspect ratio correctly? Or is whitespace allowed?

Comment: what do you mean by "cross-browser"? How far back do you need to support in terms of old browser versions?

Comment: @Spudley I've seen the CSS3 tag so I thought was obvious... :|

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715766/support-background-size-property-on-older-browsers/

Comment: It's happening mostly on mobile device browsers and some laptops as well... I would like to keep the ratio but my main concern is that the image is getting cutted to the edge of the screen, so if you scroll you'll see white... I'm not sure if explain correctly...

Comment: @Spudley is not the same I'm asking here... what I'm saying is that the image is cutted and I want to prevent that...

Comment: @roXon - No, it's not obvious. I've seen the css3 tag used by people looking for IE6/7/8 support plenty of times in the past. When people use the term "cross-browser" without qualifying it, it always leaves room for doubt.

Comment: @met.lord - fair enough. In that case, I guess standard CSS `background-size:cover;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g4v4hgxp/)**

```
body{
  background: url(bg.jpg) fixed 50% / cover;
}
```

<sub>Remember to set `html, body{ height:100%; }` if needed; for non-`body` elements you can remove `fixed`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that...What I meant, is when you see a website with a full image background, and you scroll (because you're on a mobile or small resolution device) you shouldn't see white... I would like to get the image taking 100% size not of the screen size, but of the content... Does that make sense?

Comment: background-size:cover is not cross browser.

Comment: @472084 in a couple of years it will be ;)